# consume SOAP web service in Portable class library

Tags: soap, portable-class-library

I've portable class library that targets .NET framework 4.5,silverlight 4 and higher and windows phone 8.I want to consume SOAP service in that PCL using add service reference.

```
    ServiceReference1.TadawulMarketServicePortTypeClient c = new ServiceReference1.TadawulMarketServicePortTypeClient(ServiceReference1.TadawulMarketServicePortTypeClient.EndpointConfiguration.TadawulMarketServiceSOAP11port_http, new EndpointAddress(""));
        c.getMarketSummaryCompleted+=c_getMarketSummaryCompleted;
        c.getMarketSummaryAsync();
    }

    private void c_getMarketSummaryCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.getMarketSummaryCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

when I use this code At PCL the service returns null but when I use it in Windows phone app it returns data!

I wanted to know the reason for that and how to consume this service correctly.